# Presentation of (presumably) inner direct product $G_1\times G_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, direct-product

Let $G_1=\langle S_1\mid R_1\rangle,\ G_2=\langle S_2 \mid R_2 \rangle $ and $S_1\cap S_2=\emptyset$.

Show that $G_1\times G_2=\langle S_1\cup S_2\mid R_1\cup R_2\cup R\rangle$ where $R=\{S^{-1}T^{-1}ST=1\},\ S\in S_1,\ T\in S_2$.

> Question:
>
> Since $S_1\cup S_2$ isn't a subgroup of the outer direct product, one should probably identify the outer with the inner product for given presentations. Is that correct? If yes, what are the factors of the inner product that is isomorphic to $G_1\times G_2$? I would assume they are the smallest normal subgroups $N_1$ and $N_2$ containing $S_1$ and $S_2$.

Comment: It seems you're talking about _presentations_ of groups and it has nothing to do with representation theory.

Comment: You're right. I edited the tags.

Comment: Fixed all occurrences of "representation" as such.

Comment: Well, it is easy to see that there's an epimorphism $f:<S_1\cup S_2>\to G_1\times G_2$ and that $R_1\cup R_2\cup R\subset\ker(f)$. The difficult part is to show that actually the kernel is generated by this set. Not sure yet how to do it.